# Shallow copy a string array in the constructor

Tags: c++

I have a string array (`string references[10]`) in my header file as a private variable of a class.

How can I shallow copy if I have a constructor in that class `tome(string *initialList)`?

I want to set `references = initialList;`

What is the best way to do it?

Header file:

```
#ifndef TOME_H
#define TOME_H
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class tome;

ostream &operator << (ostream &, const tome &);

class tome
{
public:
    tome(string , int, string);
    tome(string, int, string , string*);
    ~tome();
    int getTomeSize();
    string getSpell(int) const;
    string* getReferences();
    string getName();
    string getAuthor();
    tome operator+(string* add);
    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &output, const tome &t);
    void operator=(const tome &oldTome);
private:
    string references[10];
    string tomeName;
    string author;
    int spellsStored;

    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &, const tome &);
};
#endif
```

tome.cpp Constructor:

```
tome::tome(string name, int tomeSize, string authorName, string* initialList)
{
tomeName = name;
author = authorName;
spellsStored = tomeSize;
}
```

Comment: May you post the code please? It'll be easier to answer this way.

Comment: Updating it now

Comment: Shallow copy is a bad idea. Why would you want to do that? It can cause unexpected or undefined behavior.

Comment: Then how can I make I deep copy

Comment: Pass `initialList`'s count as another parameter, and then loop through `initialList` copying each string to the corresponding element of `references`. Or use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for everything, as it has an `operator=`

Comment: How the initialList declared in the function that creates this object?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking about: shallow-copying of the array itself or shallow-copying of its elements. A raw array itself is a single-level data structure in C++. There's no differentiation into shallow- and deep-copying of arrays. But if you are asking about shallow-copying of individual `std::string` elements of the array, then it is just not possible. `std::string`'s interface fully controls its copying and there's no "shallow-copy" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array, either raw or in form of `std::array`, *always* contains the data (in case of an array of pointers, the "data" is the pointers!), so if you have an array of `std::string`, you cannot shallow copy as std::string does not provide shallow copies.

For shallow copies, you need references or pointers (not considering visibility, adjust yourself as needed):

```
class A
{
    std::array<std::string, 10> data; // using std::array for its superior interface...
};
class B
{
    std::array<std::string, 10>* data; // references an array of some A
}
```

Obviously, you now need some life time management of whatever form to assure that the referenced `A` is not destroyed as long as the referencing `B` is still alive, or at least, as long as `B` still uses this reference. If you don't do this right, you end up either in undefined behaviour or with memory leaks...

You get this memory management for free if you use a smart pointer:

```
class C
{
    std::shared_ptr<std::array<std::string, 10>> data;
};
```

Now different `C` (as many as you like) can share arbitrary data, it will be deleted as soon as all `C` referencing it are destroyed, but not earlier, and you are safe from both problems above. Shallow copies now are done by simply assigning the smart pointer to another one:

```
C::C(std::shared_ptr<std::array<std::string, 10>>& data) : data(data) { }
//                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^
// std::shared_ptr's constructor does the necessary stuff...
```

However, changes to the data in one `C` get visible to all other `C` sharing the same array. This *can* be desired in some cases, might lead to great surprises in other ones if you don't handle the matter carefully.

You might prefer deep copies instead to avoid trouble. I recommend using `std::array` because it has a superior interface similar to the one of `std::vector`, so you can easily assign correctly; let's extend above class `A` appropriately:

```
A::A(std::array<std::string, 10>& data) : data(data) { }
//                                        ^^^^^^^^^^
// simply assign, std::array's constructor does the rest...
```

If you insist on having raw arrays:

```
class D
{
    std::string[10] data;
    D(std::string* data)
    {
        std::copy(data, data + 10, this->data);
    }
};
```

Assuming we always have arrays of length 10 – you can get into great trouble if this condition is violated at some time somewhere. Better is passing the size together with the array and having appropriate checks. You see, `std::array` avoids all this trouble and additionally a mismatch between raw array and length being passed (on the other hand, you cannot pass sub-arrays this way; you could, though, provide an overload with two additional parameters `size_t offset, size_t length` to the approach below allowing to select sub ranges). If you want to be able to pass arrays of arbitrary lengths:

```
template <size_t N>
A::A(std::array<std::string, N>& data)
{
    //static_assert(N <= 10); // if you don't want to discard surplus data silently...
    //std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), this->data.begin());

    std::copy
    (
        data.data(),
        data.data() + std::min(N, this->data.size()),
        this->data.begin()
    );
}
```

Finally: Appropriate typedefs can safe you quite some typing on one hand and, but more important, prevent you from errors (use constants as well):

```
class C
{
    using Data = std::shared_ptr<std::array<std::string, 10>>;
    Data data;
    C(Data& data) : data(data) { }
};

class A
{
    static size_t const DataLength = 10;
    template <size_t N>
    A(std::array<std::string, N>& data)
    {
         static_assert(N <= DataLength);
         std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), this->data.begin());
    }
};
```